# What are the alternatives to TableDiff utility on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, comparison

Currently we are using the TableDiff utility during an SSIS data load to update a live table in production from a staging table (which has the latest data to be updated - could be insert/update/delete).

But TableDiff takes quite a bit of time to identify differences and create the sql scripts for the job to use to update (from few hours - to indentify about a few 1000s of rows of updates to few 100,000s of rows of updates taking up to a few days).

Are there any better alternatives to TableDiff utility on SQL Server 2008 or maybe better processes/ideas?

**Update:**
Looking for both product/utility options as well as *better algorithms* to make it faster

Comment: critical issue. I've faced this kind of situation few days ago. I've used an extra column of `Timestamp`(or any Flag) in the staging table. Whenever load data to destination table, check `Timestamp`(or Flag); and after data fully loaded, update the column(Timestamp or flag). In that scenario, didn't need to track `Deleted` data, so it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why calling a stored procedure with a MERGE statement in it is not an option here? I was using this approach in my DTS days.

Comment: hello. Google brought me this http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/EDW/77100/ 
it has good explanation of MERGE statement. I suggest you first connect to your development database with Management Studio, open a query window and experiment with the MERGE command for your stage and destination tables. If you see benefit, you will integrate it into SSIS. The link above says you don't have to even create a stored procedure for this, you can put the MERGE statement directly into Execute SQL task.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest Red-Gate's SQL Data Compare but it's a bit pricey. (there's a free trial if you want to check it out if it works for you)

Answer (score 0):

RedGate supposedly is the best.

I sometimes use [Atlantis](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/sqleverywhere/default.aspx) tools

They are quite heavy, but do their job